# How to center a button vertically and horizontally using twitter bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, button, center

I am basically trying to center a bootstrap button both HORIZONTALLY and VERTICALLY.

Comment: Use line-height, or display table-cell and vertical-align: middle or top: 50% left: 50% margin-left: (- half size of the button), please put your html markup and css here or make a jsfiddle

Comment: Seems I have resolved it. Here is a jsfiddle of what I did. http://jsfiddle.net/Dv2L6/

Comment: For some reason it wasnt working earlier when i used this code.

Comment: You forget to put the class .centered in your example..i´m glad that i help you

Comment: I fixed the example! Sorry about that :) Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Before adding messy and unnecessary inline css to your buttons, have you looked at their documentation? Bootstrap offers a pretty solid grid system as well. I would take a look here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

After using the grid system to align it horizontally, you could use line-height as suggested earlier, or play with the margins and padding a bit.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I resolved it just fine using "unnecessary inline css". And yes I spent some time reading the bootstrap documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this by adding another id or class and then add CSS for this id or class to make it centered horizontally and vertically..........